# Difference in type() and hasattr() between Python 3 and Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I am trying to check type of `class` declaration in `Python 3` and `Python 2`, I get strange results, as followings show,

```
>>> #python 2.7.6
>>> class MyClass:
...     pass
... 
>>> type(MyClass)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> hasattr(MyClass, '__call__')
False
```

The `type` of `MyClass` in `Python 2` is `classobj` and `MyClass` has no `__call__` attribute. This is what I expect.

```
>>> #python 3.3.3
>>> class MyClass:
...     pass
... 
>>> type(MyClass)
<class 'type'>
>>> hasattr(MyClass, '__call__')
True
```

However, in `Python 3`, the `type` of `MyClass` is `class 'type'`, and `MyClass` has `__call__` attribute although I don't declare it within `MyClass`.

I guess the reason is that in `Python 3`, `MyClass` is a `type`, and `type` has `__call__` attribute, am I right? and why `Python 3` change the behavior of `type` function like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What changed is that all classes in 3.x are **new-style classes** by default. Your Python 2 classes did not inherit from `object`, so Python thought it was an old-style class.

In 2.7.5:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> type(MyClass)
<type 'type'>
>>> hasattr(MyClass, '__call__')
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I have another question. If I set `c = MyClass()`, and `callable(c)` will return false, but `hasattr(MyClass, '__call__')` returns true. So why `callable(c)` returns false?

Comment: @mitchelllc You did not override the default `__call__`, so `callable(c)` shows as `False`. However, if you inherit from a `function`, it will be `callable()` by default.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 well, I am a little confused. `callable(c)` returns false because I don't override the default `__call__`, but why `hasattr(MyClass, '__call__')` return true? Big thanks!

Comment: @mitchelllc You're mixing up the class and its instances. `callable(MyClass)` is true. `hasattr(c, '__call__')` is false.

Comment: Hi @delnan, thank you for the point. I find these words help me understand it. `classes are callable (calling a class returns a new instance); class instances are callable if they have a __call__() method.` from http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable